# Cannot load a ResNet50 pretrained model from Tensorflow 1.15 to Tensorflow 2.4

Tags: tensorflow, keras, valueerror, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model

I have a finetuned ResNet50 model as follow

```
def get_model_RES(img_width, img_height, img_channels, num_classes, name_weight = None):
    from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

    base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
                          input_shape=(img_width, img_height, img_channels), pooling='avg',
                          classes=num_classes)

    x = base_model.output
    x = Dense(256)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
    if name_weight != None:
        model.load_weights(name_weight)
    print('load Resnet done!')
    return model
```

I trained this model using Tensorflow/Keras 1.15 and I already saved the model weights after training. Today, I upgrade the Tensorflow and Keras to 2.4. However, when I load my weights using this exact finetuned ResNet50 model, I receive a ValueError

```
  File "D:\lst_model.py", line 41, in get_model_RES
    model.load_weights(name_weight)
  File "C:\Users\ICDSP-TRONG\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu_v2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2234, in load_weights
    hdf5_format.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "C:\Users\ICDSP-TRONG\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu_v2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 710, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "C:\Users\ICDSP-TRONG\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu_v2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ICDSP-TRONG\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu_v2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3706, in batch_set_value
    x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x)))
  File "C:\Users\ICDSP-TRONG\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu_v2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 891, in assign
    (tensor_name, self._shape, value_tensor.shape))
ValueError: Cannot assign to variable conv3_block1_0_conv/kernel:0 due to variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512) and value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible
```

I guess Tensorflow/Keras changed the ResNet 50 architecture in version 2.4. So how can I reuse my pretrained model weights in version 1? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that I found is to reuse the `resnet50.py` file written by the Keras team on Github https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py
After changing few lines of code, I have

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import warnings
import keras

WEIGHTS_PATH = ('https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/'
                'releases/download/v0.2/'
                'resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = ('https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/'
                       'releases/download/v0.2/'
                       'resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')

backend = None
layers = None
models = None
keras_utils = None


def identity_block(input_tensor, kernel_size, filters, stage, block):
    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters
    bn_axis = 3
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1),
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name=conv_name_base + '2a')(input_tensor)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2a')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size,
                      padding='same',
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name=conv_name_base + '2b')(x)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2b')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters3, (1, 1),
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name=conv_name_base + '2c')(x)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2c')(x)

    x = keras.layers.add([x, input_tensor])
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    return x


def conv_block(input_tensor, kernel_size, filters, stage, block, strides=(2, 2)):

    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters
    bn_axis = 3
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1), strides=strides,
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name=conv_name_base + '2a')(input_tensor)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2a')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding='same',
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name=conv_name_base + '2b')(x)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2b')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters3, (1, 1),
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name=conv_name_base + '2c')(x)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '2c')(x)

    shortcut = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters3, (1, 1), strides=strides,
                             kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                             name=conv_name_base + '1')(input_tensor)
    shortcut = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(
        axis=bn_axis, name=bn_name_base + '1')(shortcut)

    x = keras.layers.add([x, shortcut])
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    return x


def ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000):

    if not (weights in {'imagenet', None} or os.path.exists(weights)):
        raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                         '`None` (random initialization), `imagenet` '
                         '(pre-training on ImageNet), '
                         'or the path to the weights file to be loaded.')

    if weights == 'imagenet' and include_top and classes != 1000:
        raise ValueError('If using `weights` as `"imagenet"` with `include_top`'
                         ' as true, `classes` should be 1000')

    if input_tensor is None:
        img_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    else:
        if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
            img_input = keras.layers.Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
        else:
            img_input = input_tensor
    bn_axis = 3


    x = keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3, 3), name='conv1_pad')(img_input)
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (7, 7),
                      strides=(2, 2),
                      padding='valid',
                      kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                      name='conv1')(x)
    x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name='bn_conv1')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), name='pool1_pad')(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2))(x)

    x = conv_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='a', strides=(1, 1))
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='b')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='c')

    x = conv_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='a')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='b')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='c')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='d')

    x = conv_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='a')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='b')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='c')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='d')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='e')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='f')

    x = conv_block(x, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='a')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='b')
    x = identity_block(x, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='c')

    if include_top:
        x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
        x = keras.layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='fc1000')(x)
    else:
        if pooling == 'avg':
            x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
        elif pooling == 'max':
            x = keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
        else:
            warnings.warn('The output shape of `ResNet50(include_top=False)` '
                          'has been changed since Keras 2.2.0.')

    inputs = img_input
    # Create model.
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs, x, name='resnet50')

    return model
```

then I can load my pretrained model successfully.